# How can I send the user to a different URL using navigateToURL depending on clicked target?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, redirect, actionscript

I have an SWF file of a "virtual map" with different locations. When each location is clicked, the user is redirected to a hyperlink.

How would I make each location redirect to a different hyperlink?

- If the fountain was clicked, the user would be redirected to http://different.com
- If the castle was clicked, the user would be redirected to http://something.com

You can download the SWF from [here](http://www.filedropper.com/aaa_2) or view it online: http://www.fastswf.com/NInMHKU

Here is ActionScript code which makes possible for the user to be redirected when clicking on a location:

```
package
{
   import flash.net.URLRequest;
   import flash.net.navigateToURL;
   import flash.events.MouseEvent;

   public class Map
   {
       public function Map()
       {
       }

       public function gotoLocation(param1:int) : void
       {
           if(param1 != 999)
           {
               navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.baidu.com"),"_blank");
            }
        }

        private function closeMap(param1:MouseEvent = null) : void
        {

        }
    }
}
```

---

After decompiling the SWF file with a program called JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler, I discovered that there's two different AS files for each location on the map. As an example, below are the files for the fountain.

**Source of: Flumsfountain_499.as**

```
package SkylandersSuperchargersMap_26_10_15_fla
{
   import flash.display.MovieClip;

   public dynamic class Flumsfountain_499 extends MovieClip
   {


      public function Flumsfountain_499()
      {
         super();
         addFrameScript(0,this.frame1,1,this.frame2);
      }

      function frame1() : *
      {
         stop();
      }

      function frame2() : *
      {
         stop();
      }
   }
}
```

**Source of: flumsfountainlPU_520.as**

```
package SkylandersSuperchargersMap_26_10_15_fla
{
   import flash.display.MovieClip;

   public dynamic class flumsfountainlPU_520 extends MovieClip
   {


      public function flumsfountainlPU_520()
      {
         super();
         addFrameScript(18,this.frame19);
      }

      function frame19() : *
      {
         stop();
      }
   }
}
```

---

**Previously I tried...**

I was able to use [**RABCDAsm**](https://github.com/CyberShadow/RABCDAsm) to decompile the SWF into many different files and here is the code (*source file:* `Map.class.asasm`) which is produced by the AS3 project at the top of this question:

```
  trait method QName(PackageNamespace(""), "gotoLocation")
   method
    name "gotoLocation"
    refid "TestGotoLocationFunction/instance/gotoLocation"
    param QName(PackageNamespace(""), "int")
    returns QName(PackageNamespace(""), "void")
    flag HAS_PARAM_NAMES
    paramname "param1"
    body
     maxstack 4
     localcount 2
     initscopedepth 0
     maxscopedepth 1
     code
      getlocal0
      pushscope

      getlocal1
      pushshort           999
      ifeq                L13

      getlex              QName(PackageNamespace("flash.net"), "navigateToURL")
      getglobalscope
      findpropstrict      QName(PackageNamespace("flash.net"), "URLRequest")
      pushstring          "http://www.baidu.com"
      constructprop       QName(PackageNamespace("flash.net"), "URLRequest"), 1
      pushstring          "_blank"
      call                2
      pop
L13:
      returnvoid
     end ; code
    end ; body
   end ; method
  end ; trait
```

Comment: _Note_ : **(1)** Make sure you test that it's possible to re-compile a **working** new swf from that JPEXS decompiled code. **(2)** Also that FastSWF.com link gives a "modified" SWF (like base64 or such?) so when it's saved from site it then can't be opened as a valid SWF in a decompiler (the bytes don't even begin with expected "CWS" or "FWS" byte values). I've replaced FastSWF link with testable link from your previous Question. Finally confirm that you can successfully re-compile a new SWF. Then we'll know what Answer you need where, otherwise editing that `.ASasm` code is your best option.

Comment: @VC.One Hi, the reason why there is a link to a modified SWF is because the proper one which you edited into the post does not redirect to the same URL when a location is clicked. Can you recommend me a website I can upload the modified SWF to, one which can be opened as a valid SWF in a decompiler? I will look into whether the SWF can be re-compiled.

Comment: I mean the website itself is doing some kind of copy-protection thing with uploaded swf's (try saving the swf for test purposes only gives an encrypted file). Not a problem if online viewing only but an Answerer will need to re-create your issue by decompiling the original swf.

Comment: @VC.One I've updated my post with a link to download the SWF. I've discovered that with JPEXS, rather than decompiling and recompiling, you can directly edit the AS code and save it, which will update the SWF file.

Comment: Do you have permission to modify the swf file you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit file ***com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.Map.as***:

```
  public function gotoLocation(param1:int) : void
  {
     if(param1 == 190)
     {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.different.com"),"_blank");
     }
     else if(param1 == 113)
     {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.something.com"),"_blank");
     }
     else
     {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.baidu.com"),"_blank");
     }
  }
```

You can find values for param1 from:

```
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.halloween_btn,818));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.sinksSub_btn,116));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.tinksTree_btn,191));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.doshPalace_btn,102));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.gongsPipenest_btn,103));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.shoppingMall_btn,104));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.castleGam_btn,113));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.flem_manor_btn,125));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.partyBox_btn,10013));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.rumsCove_btn,129));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.flumsFountain_btn,190));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.riggsPalladium_btn,111));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.post_btn,120));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.figgsCafe_btn,156));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.grottoClub_btn,109));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.labsLab_btn,172));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.nestStreet_btn,115));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.nest_btn,5));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.binPetsParadiseRight_btn,100));
     this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.MapLocation(this,this.binPetsParadiseLeft_btn,101));
```

Each line:

> <strike>this.mapLocs.push(new com.binweevils.externalUIs.map.</strike>MapLocation(this,**this.flumsFountain_btn**,**190**));

Provides the `buttonMC` and `roomID` which further can be used as param1 for the `gotoLocation()` to conditionally navigate the browser.

You can download the swf from https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_AKfmXEaZvQUldqNkU3ZW9ZMTg

> NOTE: You shouldn't decompile and use others property without
>   permission unless it is for educational purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm about to try it out. Could I ask where you got the list of values for param1 from?

Comment: They were found in same Map.as file

Answer (score 0):

If the castle or any other element could be given a property with a unique string value you could try something like

```
private function mClick(me:MouseEvent):void{
    goToURL(me.target.url_String); 
}

private function goToURL(urlString:String):void{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url_String));
}
```

You just need to have a property called `url_String` in the class that the castle is an instance of (obviously it will need to be a custom class) and when you instantiate that class define its property with the url that you want the castle to go to. Like:

```
 var castle:Location = new Location("http://www.baidu.com");
```

Obviously `Location` would be your custom class that might look something like this:

```
public class Location extends Sprite {
    public var url_String:String;
    private function Location(s:String):void{
        url_String = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Neal and thanks for responding! I'm very new to AS, but it's quite exciting learning. After I decoded the file with RABCDAsm, I found two files for the castle in the directory `SkylandersSuperchargersMap_26_10_15_fla`, named **gamscastle_293.script.asasm** and **gamscastle_293.class.asasm**. Which one would I amend to give the element a property with a unique string like you mentioned?

Comment: Ooh, probably the class one

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. You know the code in my original post, should I remove that?

Comment: I don't know. As was mentioned some of your code is not as3. Hopefully you know that and aren't putting that in your project.

Comment: mClick wasn't meant to be a class at all. It's a function

Comment: Just put it in your main document class as I've written it. Again you'll need to make a Location class if you don't already have one. Question: the castle you click on or fountain... what are they? Movie clips? Or are they a custom class that extends Sprite or extends movie clip already? If they are already a custom class you just need to edit that class. If not, you need to make one.

Comment: I used RABCDAsm to decompile the SWF file and have uploaded it here: http://www.filedropper.com/aaa-0 From looking at the files, I believe they all have custom classes.

Comment: Can you suggest which free program I can use to decompile the SWF file and then edit the AS code?

Comment: No I cannot. I don't know anything about that

Comment: It looks as though you already decompiled it... you can edit in Flash Builder, Flash Develop, or Notepad ++ or Flex

Comment: I used rabcadsm to decompile it, but you told me it's not AS code

Comment: The block that ends with a bunch of "`end ;`" one after the other is the one that is not as3. The rest of it is

Comment: "Decompile" does not turn code from one language into code in another language. There is no "Google translate" for code. Decompiled means take a program of which you do not have the source code, and turn it into the source code (sort of). But the code you have there that we are talking about just isn't AS3, so you have to deal with that.

Comment: Maybe if you figure out what that code does, you can translate it by hand into AS3, and maybe not. I can't tell what it does just by looking at it. I don't know that language.

Comment: Hi Neal, I think there's some confusion. As the code you mentioned is not AS3, I'm going to ignore it and start from scratch. So I have the SWF file. Step two, I need to decompile the SWF file. How do I do this?

Comment: Good news, I was able to decompile it and found the AS code for each location. Where should I put the `mClick` and `goToURL` functions? http://prntscr.com/d91srx

Comment: If you can paste the code into your post (click "edit" below your post) I'll look at it tonight.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that. Would you also like me to upload the decompiled SWF to a file sharing site?

Comment: Not at this juncture.